# Products check list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE!** I just noticed for some unknown reason that after each checkbox there is a hidden field with the same name always set to false by default. I didn't put a hidden field after them? Here's the firebug and the value="true", not sure why it says that because it's not even checked.

```
<div style="display: inline;">
<input id="IsSmall" type="checkbox" value="true" name="IsSmall">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="IsSmall">
S
</div>
```

Here's the UI: list of products and beside each list is a checkbox to indicate whether the customer has selected small, medium or large.

I'm using vs2008, mvc 1.0, jquery, sqlserver 2005

In the View how can I get the checkbox values to postback to the server? The funny thing is the product name posts back fine?

**Model**

```
namespace PostingListItems.ViewModels
{
    public struct Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Sizes { get; set; }
        public bool HasSmall
        {
            get
            {
                return Sizes.IndexOf("S") != -1;
            }
        }
        public bool IsSmall { get; set; }
        public bool HasMedium
        {
            get
            {
                return Sizes.IndexOf("M") != -1;
            }
        }
        public bool IsMedium { get; set; }
        public bool HasLarge
        {
            get
            {
                return Sizes.IndexOf("L") != -1;
            }
        }
        public bool IsLarge { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public ProductViewModel()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
            Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Widget1", Sizes = "S,M,L" });
            Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Widget2", Sizes = "S,M" });
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Index</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>

       <% foreach (var item in Model.Products)
          { %>
          <% var index = Model.Products.IndexOf(item); %>
             <label for="Name"><%= item.Name %></label>            
             <div style="display: <%= item.HasSmall?"inline":"none" %>;"><%=Html.CheckBox("IsSmall")%>S</div>
             <div style="display: <%= item.HasMedium?"inline":"none" %>;"><%=Html.CheckBox("IsMedium")%>M</div>
             <div style="display: <%= item.HasLarge?"inline":"none" %>;"><%=Html.CheckBox("IsLarge")%>L</div>
             <br /> 
         <% } %>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content
```

>

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();


        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC renders `checkbox` with two field, the input type checkbox and the hidden input because the browser do not submit values if the checkbox is not selected. In your code you use the same `id` in checkbox field for all the products, so you collapse the information needed to create the view model.

Answer (score 1):

I would use editor templates to generate the form, like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products) %>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
<% } %>
```

and then inside the corresponding editor template which will be automatically rendered for each element of the Products collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Product.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.Product>" %>
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name) %>

<div style="display: <%= Model.HasSmall?"inline":"none" %>;">
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSmall) %>S
</div>

<div style="display: <%= Model.HasMedium?"inline":"none" %>;">
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsMedium)%>M
</div>

<div style="display: <%= Model.HasLarge?"inline":"none" %>;">
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsLarge)%>L
</div>
<br />
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because the generated checkbox inputs do not have the correct names so that the default model binder could successfully read their values. I would recommend you reading the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) to better understand the required wire format. But in applications it is strongly recommended to always use [editor/display templates](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) as they will take care of all these conventions.